# How do I count then display specific checkboxes checked but not all on a web form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have multiple checkboxes on a form and I have code already that tally's how many are checked (see function showChecked).  What I'm trying to do now is count how many "named" boxes are checked.  For example, I want to know of "chk011","chk021", and "chk033" how many of those are checked, but I don't care about how many of the others are or not (i.e. ignore "chk001", "chk031", and "chk032").  And then return that value in a different "result".  Here is my current code...

```
<style>
        div.floater {
            position: -webkit-sticky;
            position: sticky;
            top: 0;
            left: 65%;
            width: 200px;
            padding: 5px;
            background-color: #cae8ca;
            border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
        }
</style>
        
<script>
    showChecked();
    function showChecked(){ document.getElementById("result").textContent =
"Completed = " + ((document.querySelectorAll("input:checked").length/62)*100).toFixed(0) +
'%'; }
</script>
        
</head>
<body>
    <div class="floater"><p id="result" align="center">Completed = 0%</p></div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="chk001" onclick="changeColor(); showChecked()"
        <input type="checkbox" name="chk011" onclick="changeColor(); showChecked()"
        <input type="checkbox" name="chk021" onclick="changeColor(); showChecked()"
        <input type="checkbox" name="chk031" onclick="changeColor(); showChecked()"
        <input type="checkbox" name="chk032" onclick="changeColor(); showChecked()"
        <input type="checkbox" name="chk033" onclick="changeColor(); showChecked()"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the names you want to check  in an array, then, in your function, select all checked inputs and use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter out the ones where the `names` array does not include their `name` attribute, then get the length of the resulting array.

```js
const named = ["chk011", "chk021", "chk033"]
showChecked();

function showChecked() {
  document.getElementById("result").textContent = "Completed = " + ((document.querySelectorAll("input:checked").length / 62) * 100).toFixed(0) + '%';
  const namedChecked = [...document.querySelectorAll("input:checked")].filter(e => named.includes(e.name)).length;
  console.log(namedChecked);
}
```

```css
div.floater {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 65%;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #cae8ca;
  border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
}
```

```html
<div class="floater">
  <p id="result" align="center">Completed = 0%</p>
</div>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk001" onclick="showChecked()">
<input type="checkbox" name="chk011" onclick="showChecked()">
<input type="checkbox" name="chk021" onclick="showChecked()">
<input type="checkbox" name="chk031" onclick="showChecked()">
<input type="checkbox" name="chk032" onclick="showChecked()">
<input type="checkbox" name="chk033" onclick="showChecked()">
```

Comment: I tweaked it ever so slightly
`const named = ["chk011", "chk021", "chk033"]
showChecked();

function showChecked() {
 document.getElementById("result1").textContent = "Overall Completion " + ((document.querySelectorAll("input:checked").length / 62) * 100).toFixed(0) + '%';
 document.getElementById("result2").textContent = "Servers Left " + [...document.querySelectorAll("input:checked")].filter(e => named.includes(e.name)).length;
}`
So that I get both result1 and 2 now, but your instructions did the trick, thank you Spctric